# PowerShell Remove-Item - Wildcard after a string?

Tags: powershell

Sorry this is so basic. I have an already-defined string which is a filepath without the extension.

```
$filepathwithoutextension
```

I want to remove all files starting with this filepath (so basically all files with the same name (but different extensions) get removed. I would use a wildcard (*), like:

```
Remove-Item $filepathwithoutextension.*
```

But obviously this syntax is wrong. How do I successfully do this in PowerShell? Many thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `$filepathwithoutextension`?

Comment: just something like "C:/Path/To/Filewithoutextension"

Comment: How do you know the syntax is wrong? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Use quotes `"$filepathwithoutextension.*"`. Otherwise Powershell assumes your are trying to access a property with that dot after your variable.